Post-hoc correction of zonal statistics when pixel size is greater than vector object size
I have a dataset showing the amount of ecosystem biomass that would be impacted if different construction projects were built. The data had been compiled (by someone else) using zonal statistics to identify all pixels overlapping each projects access road, and then summed up as total project biomass.
The problem is that the pixel is 400m by 400m, and the roads are only 30m wide. It dramatically over estimates the amount of biomass impacted by roads.
Ideally, the dataset creators could have recorded the area of each pixel affected and then I could adjust for that. But they did not!
Thus, I am looking for a post hoc correction to this issue. In my mind, I can estimate the ratio of pixel size to the estimated actual road size, and then multiply the project-level biomass by this ratio as a "post-hoc correction." I could do this in excel or in R. My concern is more regarding the scientific rigour of this approach:
Does this seem legitimate? Can you suggest any spatial analysis principles to guide me in this post hoc correction? The analysis will ultimately go into a peer-reviewed scientific publication so I am trying to think this through.

Do you have the original raster and vector data? You could repeat the original analysis using exactextract (commandline/python) or exactextractr (R).

Unfortauntely, I did not. Otherwise, I would have redone the analysis. But thanks for the suggestion!
